# Rest-assured requests not working

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I am using Rest-Assured to test my Rest API. 
the webservice seems to be running ok, since running

```
    curl -u "admin:admin" http://localhost:8888/users/
```

i get my Users as json.

then, when trying a simple request with Rest-Assured

```
 RestAssured.authentication = basic("admin", "admin");

  expect().statusCode(200).when().get("http://localhost:8888/users/");
```

gives me the output

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8888 refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
…
```

what can this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. Changed from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and it worked. It's kind of odd that both cURL/browser worked with localhost. Guess this might be a routing problem.

Comment: It's called loopback IP for obvious reasons. This answer saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is the default address Rest Assured is sending all requests to.
So normally you dont really need to specify it.

This should work:

```
 RestAssured.authentication = basic("admin", "admin");
 RestAssured.port = 8888
 expect().statusCode(200).when().get("/users");
```